# How to define the default exe in a webjob that has multiple console app projects?

Tags: azure, console-application, azure-webjobs

I have a console app solution with multiple projects that I deploy as Azure Webobs. The deployment goes through fine but the webjob doesn't know anything about the startup project in solution. When executing the webjob it picks the first .exe file from the list and runs it. this is not correct and need to know how can I enforce the startup project to webjobs. Want to mention that I can run the startup exe from azure webjob console manually but scheduled process doesn't know about the startup exe when running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could get  answer from the [official document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs).The following is the snippet from the document. If we want to run .exe firstly, we could name it **run.exe**.

> we use the following logic to decide which file is the script to run within the job's directory:
>   Per file type we look first for a file named: **run.{file type extension}** (for example run.cmd or run.exe).
>   If it doesn't exists for all file types, we'll then look for the first file with a supported file type extension.
>   **The order of file types extension used is: .cmd, .bat, .exe, .ps1, .sh, .php, .py, .js.**
>
> The following file types are accepted as runnable scripts that can be used as a job:
>
> - fsx (using the F# fsi.exe interactive compiler)
> - cmd, .bat, .exe (using windows cmd)
> - ps1 (using powershell)
> - sh (using bash)
> - php (using php)
> - py (using python)
> - js (using node)

Comment: Can I create run.bat and include myfile.exe inside the batch file to be executed?

Comment: Based on my experience, yes, we could do that.

Comment: I create run.bat and include myfile.exe inside the batch file to be executed, so this is a workaround for startup or default exe file. Llike this

cd app_data\jobs\triggered\myapp
myapp.exe

Comment: Gotcha if using run.cmd etc. Ensure the file is stored _without_ the BOM characters or the run will fail